# Filtering a dictionary to a certain condition but it does not produce required results

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like my code to print all occurrences of words that appear once. I have produced this code below, however, the result only shows the first instance of the word occurring once but not all of them. I am not sure where the problem is and how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import re
from collections import Counter

def inspiration(text):
    quote =  re.findall(r'\w+', text.lower())
    quote_dict = dict(Counter(quote).most_common())
    quote_one = {}
    for key, value in quote_dict.items():
        if value == 1:
        quote_one[key]= value
        return quote_one
        
print(inspiration("We know what we are, but know not what we may be- William Shakespeare"))
```

Expected output: {"are":1, "but":1, "not":1, "be":1, "William":1, "Shakespeare":1}

Comment: ```quote_one[key]= value``` 4 spaces to right after ```if```, and ```return quote_one``` outside the loop

Answer (score 1):

Your `return` is **in** the `for` block so it returns at the end of the first iteration, what you need is returning after iterating on all pairs. Also you don't need the `value` as it's always `1` just return a list of words

```
def inspiration(text):
    quote = re.findall(r'\w+', text.lower())
    quote_dict = dict(Counter(quote).most_common())
    quote_one = []
    for key, value in quote_dict.items():
        if value == 1:
            quote_one.append(key)
    return quote_one
```

---

Improvements

- don't need to use `most_common`, you don't need an ordered iteration
- so don't need back wrapping to `dict`, you could keep the list of pairs

Combined with a dict-comprehension :

```
def inspiration(text):
    return [k for k, v in Counter(re.findall(r'\w+', text.lower())).items() if v == 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
import re
from collections import Counter

def inspiration(text):
    lst = re.findall(r'\w+', text.lower())
    return {k: v for k, v in Counter(lst).items() if v == 1}

print(inspiration("We know what we are, but know not what we may be- William Shakespeare"))
```

output :

```
{'are': 1, 'but': 1, 'not': 1, 'may': 1, 'be': 1, 'william': 1, 'shakespeare': 1}
```

Note :

1- There is no need for `.most_common()`

2- `Counter` is inherited from `dict`, so it has `.items()` , No need to convert it to a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

1. `quote_one[key]= value` should he indented to the right because it comes under `if` statement.
2. `return` ends the function. So it will end the function after the first iteration.

Here is the correct code

```
def inspiration(text):
    quote =  re.findall(r'\w+', text.lower())
    quote_dict = dict(Counter(quote).most_common())
    quote_one = {}
    for key, value in quote_dict.items():
        if value == 1:
            quote_one[key]= value
    return quote_one
```